# Mybatis-generator doesn't work using java 1.8 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, mybatis, mybatis-generator

i've mybatis-generator config file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">

<generatorConfiguration>
    <classPathEntry location="postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar" />


    <context id="PostgreTables" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true" />
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/orm” userId="fdx" password="password" />
        <javaTypeResolver>
            <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="false" />
        </javaTypeResolver>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.ameliore.solution.module" targetProject="orm">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
            <property name="trimStrings" value="true" />
        </javaModelGenerator>
        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage=“com.ameliore.solution.module”  targetProject="orm">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="mapper.module”  targetProject="orm">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </javaClientGenerator>
        <table schema="ores" tableName="t_dokumen_pendukung" domainObjectName="DokumenPendukung">
            <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="false"/>            
        </table>


    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

when i running nybatis-generator using command "java -jar mybatis-generator-core-1.3.2.jar -configfile ORM-config.xml  -overwrite" the result from generator is

```
XML Parser Errors occurred:

XML Parser Error on line 15: Element type "jdbcConnection" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

[result and java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvhqo.png)

on my mac, i am using java 8

anyone got error like me??

Comment: `/orm”` this is not a double Quote!

Comment: you rock Jens, thankyou. problem solved by @Jens